# How to get id of autocomplettextview?

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

I have two autocompletetextview,in my first autocomplet,I am getting response from server,

```
    {"status":"success","clientlist":[{"cid":"1","name":"margi"},{"cid":"2","name":"steven"}],"productboxtype":[{"pbxid":"1","pbxname":"1 Dozen","qtyperbox":"12"},{"pbxid":"2","pbxname":"2 Dozens","qtyperbox":"24"},{"pbxid":"3","pbxname":"3 Dozens","qtyperbox":"36"}]}
```

i am able to get names in my first autocomplete and it works fine,

Now issue is suppose user select item "margi" and its cid is 1,so again i am sending request to server and trying to get productnames of 'margi',and its response is

```
{"status":"success","clientproduct":[{"pid":"4","name":"kangan pair","unitprice":"1500","boxqty":"1"}]}
```

but after selection of steven still it shows kangan pari in second autocomplete

```
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();



         try {

             JsonParseClientList jp=new JsonParseClientList();
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             List<SuggestGetSetClientList> list =jp.getParseJsonWCF(acTextView.getText().toString());

                 for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
                 {
                   if(list.get(i).getName().equals(acTextView.getText().toString()))
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid",list.get(i).getId()));

                     //  catid=list.get(i).getId();



                 }

                 for(int b=0;b<list.size();b++)
                 {
                     catidtemp=list.get(b).id.toString();

                     System.out.println("cattttttiiiiddd????"+catidtemp);
                     break;
                 }

                //catidtemp=String.valueOf(selected_cid);

             System.out.println("cattttttiiiiddd????"+catidtemp);
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "clientproduct"));

             System.out.println("su gayu server ma????"+params);

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 FEEDBACK_URL, "POST", params);
             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());





             return json.getString(FEEDBACK_SUCCESS);

         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

        //parentcat.getText().clear();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject resultObject = new JsonObject(result); //where result is {"status":"success","clientlist":[{"cid":"1","name":"margi"},{"cid":"2","name":"steven"}],"productboxtype":[{"pbxid":"1","pbxname":"1 Dozen","qtyperbox":"12"},{"pbxid":"2","pbxname":"2 Dozens","qtyperbox":"24"},{"pbxid":"3","pbxname":"3 Dozens","qtyperbox":"36"}]}
JSONArray clientListArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("clientlist");
for (int i=0; i<clientListArray.length(); i++){
     JSONObject client = clientListArray.getJSONObject(i);
     int id = client.getInt("cid");
     ...
     Client clientInfo = new Client(id, name);
     clientList.add(clientInfo)
     ....
}
```

Then you can use the clientList into an adapter or something else.

You can make a class that holds your info

```
public class Client{
    int id;
    String name;

    //getter and setter for this + constructor;
}
```

To not complicate your code check: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ and look for some tutorials that explains better the usage

Also if you change adapter info don't forget to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare 'boxqty' and 'minimum_qty', in your if condition, you should not use it .length() for boxqty, as it will just compute the length of the string, user will enter, not it's value.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you select "steven" you get the clientproduct array null in response. So thats why your catch block is called and your seconds autocomplete array is not clear. That's why you get the previous value in the second Autocomplete.

Hope you can understand :)
Happy Coding :)